# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^-}| \left( 1+x^{3} \right)^{1/2}-1-x^{5} |/(\sin x-x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value, limits-without-lhopital

I am studying for my first calculus exam (well, it's half an exam), and of course we have to solve limits, without using L'Hospital rule, and using asymptotic analysis.

I can't solve this one $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{\left| \left( 1+x^{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1-x^{5} \right|}{\sin x-x}$$

Can you guide me through the solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at
$f(x)
=\frac{ ( 1+x^{3} )^{\frac{1}{2}}-1-x^{5} }{\sin x-x}
$.

By "asymptotic analysis",
as $x \to 0$,
$(1+x^3)^{\frac12}
\approx 1+\frac12 x^3 + \frac{\frac12 (-\frac12)}{2}(x^3)^2
= 1+\frac12 x^3 - \frac18 x^6
$
and
$\sin(x)
\approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}
$
so
$\sin(x)-x
\approx -\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}
$.

Therefore,
using the fact that
$ax^n+bx^m
\approx ax^n
$
as $x \to 0$
if $1 \le n < m$
and
$a\ne 0$,
$f(x)
\approx \frac{(1+\frac12 x^3- \frac18 x^6)-1-x^5}{-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}} =\frac{\frac12 x^3 - \frac18 x^6-x^5}{-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}}
\approx \frac{\frac12 x^3}{-\frac{x^3}{6}}
=-3
$.

Comment: The last equality contains a small error: in fact $$\frac{\frac12 x^3}{-\frac{x^3}{6}}
=-\frac1{12}$$ should be $$ \frac{\frac12 x^3}{-\frac{x^3}{6}}
=-3$$

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Divide and multiply by $x^3$, and above multiply and divide by the conjugate expression which is $(1+x^3)^{1/2}+(1+x^5)^2$ 
NExt to compute the fraction below use De l'Hospital rule two times to find $-1/6$ and above after some simplification the result follows easly.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I can't use L'Hospital rule.